# Highlight last clicked div CSS

Tags: html, css

I am developing a php application which takes a search term, append some text, and returns a number of youtube videos that match the search result.  The videos are displayed in `iframes` and wrapped in `div`s like so

```
<div class="wrap" data-covertext="SomeText">
  <iframe type="text/html" width="200" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SomeVideoId" frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border-width: 30px;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-style: inset;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  transition: color 1s, border-color 2s ease, border-width 1s ease;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}


.wrap:after {
  z-index: 1;
  content: attr(data-covertext);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: transparent solid 20px;
  transition: z-index 2s, opacity 1s steps(4,end), color 500ms;
}

.wrap:hover {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.wrap:hover:after {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  z-index: -1;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  opacity: 0;
 }
```

Each div has a 'cover' over it, using the `:after` qseudo-class which is then removed on `:hover` so that they can see the embedded video.  I would like to have some way of highlighting whichever div contains that last video that they clicked.  Heres the question.  Is there a way to do this with just CSS?  I know with jQuery it would be a snap, but the whole reason for this project is to learn more advanced CSS3, so i am trying to do everything without any javascript.

I have tried using inner/outer `a` tags and utilizing `:visited` (among other pseudo-selectors/classes) but couldn't get anything to work.  Is something like this even selectable with CSS?  i know there are restrictions about which pseudo-selectors can be combined for security reasons.  any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use `:active` selector, however it will disappear after user clicks anywhere else on page. Seems like there is no pure CSS solution for this because there are no other states for this purpose. Also, CSS can not know in advance what family of links to work with if you change selection. The simpliest way to do this seems to trigger add/remove some class on click with JS/jQ.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the cover on "focus" as well as hover for accessibility purposes - users not using the mouse for example.

Comment: @AndrewDunai i think you're right, i've tried this every which way, looks like i'll have to use some javascript

Comment: @pwdst good call, i just noticed this on my phone